# Why is my program getting stuck in my do while loop?

Tags: c, syntax, do-while, prompt

[image]
[image]

My program seems to be getting stuck in the do while loop. I want it to re-prompt the user if they enter a digit that is not zero or one

Comment: Please do not post code and text output as images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: Either `x != 0` or `x != 1` will always be true, same for `y`. That makes the condition true.

Comment: Suggestion for the future (and for your current project!)... replace the complicated condition `do { ... } while (x || ...< ... && ... > ... || y);` with a function call: `do { ... } while (invalid(x, y));` and feel free to implement the complicated condition in a dozen lines inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if `x == 0`? `x != 1` will be true, and the whole condition will be true.

What if `x == 1`? `x != 0` will be true, and the whole condition will be true.

What if `x == 2`? `x != 0` will be true, and the whole condition will be true.

So, no matter what, your condition will be true, and you will continue looping.

---

You want the following to be true:

```c
(x == 0 || x == 1) && (y == 0 || y == 1)
```

So you want to loop while it's false.

```c
do { } while (!((x == 0 || x == 1) && (y == 0 || y == 1)));
```

---

`!(P && Q)` is equivalent to `!P || !Q`, and
`!(P || Q)` is equivalent to `!P && !Q`

This means the following are equivalent to the above:

```c
do { } while (!(x == 0 || x == 1) || !(y == 0 || y == 1));

do { } while ((x != 0 && x != 1) || (y != 0 && y != 1));
```